# Smart Find By Pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have code

```
public sealed class GameBoardComponent : IComponent {
}

// next code auto generated
public partial class Entity {

    public GameBoardComponent gameBoard { get { return (GameBoardComponent)GetComponent(GameComponentIds.GameBoard); } }
    public bool hasGameBoard { get { return HasComponent(GameComponentIds.GameBoard); } }

    public Entity AddGameBoard(int newColumns, int newRows) {
        var component = CreateComponent<GameBoardComponent>(GameComponentIds.GameBoard);
        component.columns = newColumns;
        component.rows = newRows;
        return AddComponent(GameComponentIds.GameBoard, component);
    }

    public Entity ReplaceGameBoard(int newColumns, int newRows) {
        var component = CreateComponent<GameBoardComponent>(GameComponentIds.GameBoard);
        component.columns = newColumns;
        component.rows = newRows;
        ReplaceComponent(GameComponentIds.GameBoard, component);
        return this;
    }

    public Entity RemoveGameBoard() {
        return RemoveComponent(GameComponentIds.GameBoard);
    }
}
```

I want to highlight or click on GameBoardComponent.

And to find all references to gameBoard, hasGameBoard, AddGameBoard, ReplaceGameBoard, RemoveGameBoard.

For AnotherComponent:

```
    public sealed class AnotherComponent : IComponent {    }
```

I would have to find another, hasAnother, AddAnother, ReplaceAnother, RemoveAnother

Is it possible to make a macro\regexp\resharper pattern search or something similar?

P.S. I try use resharper pattern search. But I did not understand how to use for search, selected string(or part of string).